# nodejs + Sendgrid Template using sendgrid/mail failure ('to' value is empty, blocked message)

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I'm using the Sendgrid Node module @sendgrid/mail and as a way to test am hard-coding the recipient email address as per the code below. When I use a template (pre built in Sendgrid) I see email To field as null and error 'blocked' in Sendgrid (there is nothing in the suppression lists btw). Sending the email without the DynamicTemplateData section works fine

```
 const msg = {
      to: 'xxx@xxxxx.com',
      from: 'yyy@yyy.com',
      subject: 'Blah',
      text: 'Blah....,
      html: '<p>Blah....</p>',
      templateId: 'd-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      dynamicTemplateData: {
        subject: subject,
        link: resetLink
      },
    };

    (async () => {
      try {
        await sgMail.send(msg);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely this is because the templateId you're using is inactive. In the Sendgrid console set it to active and try it again.

SendGrid sends 202 responses to this while blocking the "to" line -- ran into the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for someone looking for the reason.

> To send mail using Dynamic Templates, you must use the Web API
> mail.send. SMTP sends do not support Dynamic Templates.